# Is it possible to use dropbox as a service on my server?

Tags: dropbox

Please, is it possible to use dropbox  as a service on my server ?
As I see, https://github.com/dropbox is open source. 
Thank you so much for explanations. 
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for an API. 
Take a look at this:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers

An API allows you to use certain features or get certain information from the company you are using the API from.
For example:

```
Implement a google maps route planner in your website via Google Maps API 3
Implement a twitter tweet via the Twitter API
etc.
```

Comment: I need to setup a cloud service in my datacenter (like dropbox server) and people connect to my datacenter and store their files (vidéos, images, etc..) ? Is that possible using DropBox API ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want a public cloud service, where people can store files, in your dropbox folder?

Comment: Because, if that is the case, you can simply create a folder in dropbox, set it to public and create a link to your folder on your website.

Comment: If you want to use it more efficient, take a look at this: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/

Comment: Did that answer your question?